# In iPhone using phonegap is there any way to invoke camera without the preview screen?

Tags: cordova, camera

The navigator.camera.getPicture invokes the camera.

But after taking it shows a preview screen and user has to click a button to come back to the application.

Is there any way to by-pass the preview screen and come directly back to the app?
Or Is there any camera plugin available with some extra features.